# How to get a JSON node that contains a specific value?

Tags: json, jsonpath

Below is the JSON file I am trying to read nodes from. I am trying to perform contains operation. I do not want to use equals option in my json path like this - $.[?(@.name=="College Graduate - Ford")]

Could you please help me in meeting my requirement?

```
[
   {
      "incentiveId" : 123,
      "autoApplied" : "false",
      "name" : "College Graduate - Ford",
      "amount" : 750,
      "expirationDate" : "2018-12-31",
      "minimumTerm" : null,
      "maximumTerm" : null,
      "groupAffiliation" : "College/Student",
      "previousOwnership" : null
   },
   {
      "incentiveId" : 456,
      "autoApplied" : "false",
      "name" : "Lease Loyalty - Ford",
      "amount" : 500,
      "expirationDate" : "2018-07-09",
      "groupAffiliation" : null,
      "previousOwnership" : "Lease Loyalty"
   },
   {
      "incentiveId" : 789,
      "autoApplied" : "false",
      "name" : "Customer Cash - Ford",
      "amount" : 1000,
      "expirationDate" : "2018-06-04",
      "groupAffiliation" : null,
      "previousOwnership" : null
   },
   {
      "incentiveId" : 222,
      "autoApplied" : "false",
      "name" : "Military - Ford",
      "amount" : 1000,
      "expirationDate" : "2018-12-31",
      "groupAffiliation" : "Military",
      "previousOwnership" : null
   }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: if I understood your question correctly, your trying achieve contains operations. So am I correct?

Comment: @Sree Yes. That’s right

Answer (score 2):

```
$.[?(/College/.test(@.name))]
```

Here I am using the test the RegExp test( ) method (which JSONPath evals behind the scenes) . This will perform the contains operation.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tested your JSON Path In https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/ but it is not working

Comment: try it out in http://jsonpath.com/. I will take look at the website you mentioned

Comment: just tried it out in another website and it seems to be working correctly https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/ .

Comment: not sure why it is not working in jsonpath.curiousconcept.com

Answer (score 0):

you can use filter to get array from array which elements satisfy the condition.

```
colleagues = json.filter(node => node.name.match("College"))
```

result:

```
[
  {
    "incentiveId": 123,
    "autoApplied": "false",
    "name": "College Graduate - Ford",
    "amount": 750,
    "expirationDate": "2018-12-31",
    "minimumTerm": null,
    "maximumTerm": null,
    "groupAffiliation": "College/Student",
    "previousOwnership": null
  }
]
```